# Class coupling of two in empty constructor (VStudio code analysis)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

Visual studio code analysis reports a a class coupling of two for this constructor:

```
protected AcceptInvitation()
{
}
```

can someone explain why? First I thought it was because of other classes where dependent of it. But I used "Find all usages" and none was reported.

so how can I figure out why Visual Studio reports "2" for it?

Then I got another constructor:

```
public AcceptInvitation(int accountId, string invitationKey)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(invitationKey)) throw new ArgumentNullException("invitationKey");
    if (accountId <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("accountId");

    AccountId = accountId;
    InvitationKey = invitationKey;
}
```

.. which reports "4" as class coupling. `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and `ArgumentNullException` is obvious. What are the other two? From what I've read `string` is considered to be a primitive and not counted.

The whole class:

```
/// <summary>
///     You must create an account before accepting the invitation
/// </summary>
public class AcceptInvitation : Request<AcceptInvitationReply>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a new instance of <see cref="AcceptInvitation" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">username</param>
    /// <param name="password">clear text password</param>
    /// <param name="invitationKey">Key from the generated email.</param>
    public AcceptInvitation(string userName, string password, string invitationKey)
    {
        if (userName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        if (invitationKey == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("invitationKey");

        UserName = userName;
        Password = password;
        InvitationKey = invitationKey;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a new instance of <see cref="AcceptInvitation" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accountId">Existing account</param>
    /// <param name="invitationKey">Key from the generated email.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     <para>
    ///         Invite to an existing account.
    ///     </para>
    /// </remarks>
    public AcceptInvitation(int accountId, string invitationKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(invitationKey)) throw new ArgumentNullException("invitationKey");
        if (accountId <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("accountId");

        AccountId = accountId;
        InvitationKey = invitationKey;
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Serialization constructor
    /// </summary>
    protected AcceptInvitation()
    {
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     The email that was used when creating an account.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     <para>
    ///         Do note that this email can be different compared to the one that was used when sending the invitation. Make
    ///         sure that this one is assigned to the created account.
    ///     </para>
    /// </remarks>
    public string AcceptedEmail { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Invite to an existing account
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     <para>
    ///         Alternative to the <see cref="UserName" />/<see cref="Password" /> combination
    ///     </para>
    /// </remarks>
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Email that the inviation was sent to
    /// </summary>
    public string EmailUsedForTheInvitation { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    ///     First name
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Invitation key from the invitation email.
    /// </summary>
    public string InvitationKey { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Last name
    /// </summary>
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     password
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="UserName" />
    public string Password { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Username as entered by the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     <para>Used together with <see cref="Password" /></para>
    ///     <para>Alternative to <see cref="AccountId" /></para>
    /// </remarks>
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Base class and its generic type parameter. You have an implicit `base()` in both constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code for your entire class, my assumption is that you have two class fields that are initialized inline. For example:

```
class Class1 
{
    private Person = new Person();
    private Automobile = new Automobile();

    protected Class1() { }
}
```

The above class will show class coupling of 2 for the protected constructor because running the constructor will cause those two fields to initialize.

---

After seeing the entire class, it is clear that the coupling is due to the inheritance from Request<AcceptInvitationReply>.

The generated IL for the protected constructor looks like this:

```
.method family hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance void class YourNamespace.Request`1<class YourNamespace.AcceptInvitationReply>::.ctor()
    IL_0006: nop
    IL_0007: nop
    IL_0008: ret
}
```

As you can see, the constructor is definitely coupled to those two classes.

Comment: Great point, unfortunately that isn't the case for me. I added the whole class

Comment: Your class inherits from Request<AcceptInvitationReply>. This means that your constructor must call the constructor on the Request<> class (even if that constructor is not defined). In order to make that call, the constructor must know about both the Request<> class and the AcceptInvitationReply class.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit `base()` in both constructors.

This creates a coupling with your base class and because its generic, you are seeing two additional  couplings; the base class and its generic type argument. If it weren't generic, you'd have only one extra coupling.